# Why does the iOS simulator load my iOS bundle but the device does not?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, bundle

I have created a bundle with a storyboard and a simple button to perform an alert.
This .bundle file I have then drag and dropped into my other Xcode project to be used.
When building the project the bundle appears in the root folder of the app.
I load the bundle with the following code:

```
NSString* fullPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"OCRSubBundle.bundle"];

NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:fullPath];

NSString *bundleIdentifier = [bundle bundleIdentifier];

NSLog(@"Bundle identifier for subbundle: %@", bundleIdentifier);

NSLog(@"Storyboard with relative path bundle path: %@", bundle);

[bundle load];

NSLog(@"Storyboard with relative path bundle path: %@", bundle);
```

Then I load the storyboard which is inside the bundle like so:

```
UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"defaultStoryboard" bundle:bundle];

UIViewController *vc = [sb instantiateInitialViewController];

[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

In the simulator the vc loads perfectly and I can also click the button on the storyboard and the alert window I implemented in the viewController appears.

BUT on the device I the bundle isn't even loaded!

The NSLog before [bundle load] gives me:

```
Storyboard with relative path bundle path: NSBundle </var/containers/Bundle/Application/2FAD31A9-F6FD-4B74-9596-22336A8216DD/OCRModuleSubBundle.app/OCRSubBundle.bundle> (not yet loaded)
```

And the NSLog after [bundle load] gives me exactly the same even though it should be loaded.

On the simulator the second NSLog gives me:

```
Storyboard with relative path bundle path: NSBundle </Users/cassiel/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/69A83C12-6C38-4191-9607-8969367317F9/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/0467B06C-6789-4488-987D-11EBE8BC0B8F/OCRModuleSubBundle.app/OCRSubBundle.bundle> (loaded)
```

So it is definitely the problem of the bundle not being loaded properly.

Does anyone know the reason for this?
Might I have to create a Framework to be able to use it on devices?
I have been banging my head on this one for ages now.

Thank for helping out

Comment: Dynamic loading of code is not allowed on the device.   Bundles can be used to manage a set of resources, but cannot be used to load code.